# Running .NET applications without the .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I was wondering that is there any way to run application made in visual studio c# with out installing the .NET framework on client end.

One idea came to my mind may be it is crazy,that is the application that we make depends on the library files that we use in it for example System.Windows.Forms etc etc and
when ever we use some extra dll file it gets copy in the location where setup is installed in short instead of keeping the whole dot net frame work can we just specify the dependencies and export them?

Comment: AFAIK mono supports some form of static linking, but I think it doesn't work on windows. And their WinForms implementation can't compete with a native GUI framework either.

Comment: What's the motive for doing this? It seems a bit strange, installing the .NET framework is a perfectly reasonable thing to expect an end user to do (and chances are they have already.)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Doesn't Mono's WF implementation use the native widgets on Windows anyway?

Comment: berry120. I would disagree, in fact we had a lot of customers that have no admin privileges and are not able to install anything. For us what had to provide a CD only with the app on it. Currently I can live with it, but sometimes it would be nice to have an standalone application (see ILMerge) without the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you also need the runtime to be present, it's not that simple.

In short, (as @Mitch said), this is not possible.

Comment: so how come most of applications that we install dose not require dot net?

Comment: @Afnan - perhaps because they are not .NET applications? And if they _are_ then the .NET framework is already present.

Comment: I agree with you but those applications have UI like we make in winforms etc so how do they make itand in what language

Comment: @Afnan - you can write windows applications in C and C++ and many other languages.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Windows 7 machines have .NET 3.5 installed as part of OS installation.

Answer (score 2):

Well there's the [Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/), but it's not free.

Comment: Looks like an abandoned project to me. And there could be legal issues with shipping .net code with your application as well.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no, this isn't possible.

However, depending on what your reasons are for not wanting to install the framework, you may find the [.NET Framework Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) useful. This is a cutdown version of the main framework which removes libraries you may not need and therefore reduces the diskspace and resources it requires on the client machine.

Alternatively, maybe [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net) could meet your needs - whilst the Silverlight runtime would need installing, this is again a cutdown version of the CLR and can be delivered through a browser.

Answer (score 0):

What about using client profile feature of .net 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is same like you want to open Microsoft Word 2007/2010 files with extension (.docx) with Microsoft Word 2003 that only provides files with extension (.doc). :):):)